# Send Email With Specified Bold/Size/Color/Underline Text Format from a Text Cell with Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to send an Outlook e-mail, changing the text format for specific text from a specific cell in Excel.

For example, in my worksheet there's a cell with text "Jorge Bailey" and I want to edit it from "Jorge Bailey" to **Jorge Bailey**.

```vb
Sub enviar_email_gestor_maquina()

Set objeto_outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set Email = objeto_outlook.createitem(0)

Email.display

Email.to = "jorge.bailey@syngenta.com"

Email.Subject = "Seu Notebook esta Elegível a Troca - Renovação Tecnológica"
       
Link = "<span style=""font-family:Arial; font-size: 12pt; ""<a href=""https://app.smartsheet.com/b/form/3976fc184fc84380a68d0da69b8ddc6d"" >Link Formulário</a>"
   
txt1 = "<span style=""font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; color: #808000; font-size:20pt;"">Renovação Tecnológica - Troca de notebook</span>" & "<br><br>"
 
txt2 = "<span style=""font-family:Arial; font-size: 15pt;""> & Range(B5) & </span>"

Email.htmlbody = txt1 & htmltxt2 & Link & Email.htmlbody
Email.Recipients.ResolveAll

End Sub
```

What is wrong with "txt2"?**

### What about Hyperlinks?

I would like to do it with HYPERLINKS, because when you put a link from a cell in your e-mail body, the VBA gets the text and not the hyperlink.

Comment: Hi, take a time to check this code [here](https://pastebin.com/9vuHjjua)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You quoting is incorrect:

```vb
Set objeto_outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set Email = objeto_outlook.createitem(0)

Email.display

Email.to = "jorge.bailey@syngenta.com"

Email.Subject = "Seu Notebook esta Elegível a Troca - Renovação Tecnológica"
       
txt1 = "<span style='font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; color: #808000; font-size:20pt;'>" & _
         "Renovação Tecnológica - Troca de notebook</span><br><br>"
 
txt2 = "<span style='font-family:Arial; font-size: 15pt;'><b>" & Range("B5").Value & "</b></span>"
 
Link = "<span style='font-family:Arial; font-size: 12pt;'>" & _
   "<a href='https://app.smartsheet.com/b/form/3976fc184fc84380a68d0da69b8ddc6d'>Link Formulário</a></span>"

Email.htmlbody = txt1 & txt2 & Link & Email.htmlbody
Email.Recipients.ResolveAll
```